# C++ Visual Studio Release build unused code crash

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a question which is quite general, but I hope someone will be able to at least point me in the right direction.

I created my project a I was building it only in Debug mode with /MDd flag.
But it started to have perfomance issues, so I wanted to try it in Release mode to see, how it goes. 
Problem is, that when I use /MD or /MT flag and Release mode my application instantly crashes. 
So I tried to find out why. It works fine in Debug. I've tried some code changes, but nothing helped. So I decided to make my app just start and comment out rest of my code. But it was still crashing. Even when my code was unused. It didn't crash only, when I completly removed those unused parts of code.

I think it's something with variable inicialization/declaration, but I'm not quite sure what I should look for.

Could someone suggest me what can cause application to crash even if it's just Declaration/Inicialization and is not even used in RunTime?

I hope you can somehow understand what is my problem.

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: Code which crashes, when unused code is in project, but does not crash when i remove unused code.

```
    #include "core/oxygine.h"
#include "Stage.h"
#include "DebugActor.h"

//#include "Galatex.h"


using namespace oxygine;


//called each frame
int mainloop()
{
    //galatex_update();
    //update our stage
    //update all actors. Actor::update would be called also for all children
    getStage()->update();

    if (core::beginRendering())
    {
        Color clearColor(32, 32, 32, 255);
        Rect viewport(Point(0, 0), core::getDisplaySize());
        //render all actors. Actor::render would be called also for all children
        getStage()->render(clearColor, viewport);

        core::swapDisplayBuffers();
    }

    //update internal components
    //all input events would be passed to Stage::instance.handleEvent
    //if done is true then User requests quit from app.
    bool done = core::update();

    return done ? 1 : 0;
}

//it is application entry point
void run()
{
    ObjectBase::__startTracingLeaks();

    //initialize Oxygine's internal stuff
    core::init_desc desc;

#if OXYGINE_SDL || OXYGINE_EMSCRIPTEN
    //we could setup initial window size on SDL builds
    desc.w = 1800;
    desc.h = 1000;
    //marmalade settings could be changed from emulator's menu
#endif


    //galatex_preinit();
    core::init(&desc);


    //create Stage. Stage is a root node
    Stage::instance = new Stage(true);
    Point size = core::getDisplaySize();
    getStage()->setSize(size);

    //DebugActor is a helper actor node. It shows FPS, memory usage and other useful stuff
    DebugActor::show();

    //initialize this example stuff. see example.cpp
    //galatex_init();

#ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
    /*
    if you build for Emscripten mainloop would be called automatically outside.
    see emscripten_set_main_loop below
    */
    return;
#endif


    //here is main game loop
    while (1)
    {
        int done = mainloop();
        if (done)
            break;
    }
    //user wants to leave application...

    //lets dump all created objects into log
    //all created and not freed resources would be displayed
    ObjectBase::dumpCreatedObjects();

    //lets cleanup everything right now and call ObjectBase::dumpObjects() again
    //we need to free all allocated resources and delete all created actors
    //all actors/sprites are smart pointer objects and actually you don't need it remove them by hands
    //but now we want delete it by hands

    //check example.cpp
    //galatex_destroy();


    //renderer.cleanup();

    /**releases all internal components and Stage*/
    core::release();

    //dump list should be empty now
    //we deleted everything and could be sure that there aren't any memory leaks
    ObjectBase::dumpCreatedObjects();
    ObjectBase::__stopTracingLeaks();
    //end
}

#ifdef __S3E__
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    run();
    return 0;
}
#endif


#ifdef OXYGINE_SDL

#include "SDL_main.h"
extern "C"
{
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        run();
        return 0;
    }
};
#endif

#ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
#include <emscripten.h>

void one() { mainloop(); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    run();
    emscripten_set_main_loop(one, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: You need to post the code (you are claiming you have minimal example which crashes).

Comment: If you create your project from template in VS, then you dont need to worry about all those switches. You choose either Debug or Release. I suggest you create a new project and copy all the code to it.

Comment: I added code which crashes with unused code, but is fine when i remove unused code completly from project. But i dont think it will help with anyhing.

Comment: If you commented all the code - as you say `So I decided to make my app just start and comment out rest of my code` then you have some project configuration issues.

Comment: I already did copy code from project to new one, but it didn't help.

Comment: You should put the return value from `getStage()` into a temporary variable and verify it is a valid address / pointer value.

Comment: Do you have permission to change the return value of `mainloop` so it returns a `bool`?

Comment: Yes i can change return value to bool, but why would that or even getStage() have any impact on crashes? This code works. Here and even in other examples. App crashes, when I add code which is unused, so it must be something like variable inicialization or declaration problem or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'll write it here for possibly other newbies like me which would find themselves in similar sutiation.

My problem was in Initialization of static and other variables which were "outside of function". For example:

```
    MyObject object = new MyObject();    //This was the reason, why it was crashing, just had to move
                                         // initialization of such variables to function which was called with object creation.                
    void MyClass::myFunction(){

      object->doSomething();      
    }
```

So when program started inicialization of those variables caused crash of program. 
Note: It seems like it was problem with objects, cause variables like Integers or such were just fine.

Well, I'm not totally sure why this is allowed in Debug mode, but crashes Release mode right after start, maybe someone could answer under this comment and explain this behavior, I'm just begginer and I'm doing lot of bad stuff, but I'm trying and that's good, right? :D

I hope i didn't waste too much of your time guys and maybe this post will be useful to someone in future.